# QML change height of item with respect to change in height of item below it

Tags: qt, qml

I have a listview and a textarea below it. I want that the height of listview increases or decreases with respect to the size of the textarea. I tried anchoring the bottom of listview to the textarea's top, didn't work. Then I tried anchoring the top of textarea to the bottom of listview, didn't work either. Tried both together, neither that. Everytime it gives the runtime error/warning of **Binding loop detected for property "height"**
I also tried this in textarea's scope, yet I have the same runtime error/warning and no results:

```
onTextChanged: {
            listView.anchors.bottomMargin = height;
        }
```

How can I achieve this?

Here's the code:

```
    ListView{
    id: listView
//        anchors.fill: parent
    anchors.top: parent.top
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.right: parent.right
    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    anchors.bottomMargin: 0
    anchors.margins: 10
    delegate: ChatMessageItem{}
    model: listModel
    spacing: 15
}

Rectangle{
    id: rectInput
    height: childrenRect.height + 6
    width: parent.width
//        anchors.top: listView.bottom
    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    color: "#BDC3C7"
    TextArea{
        id: tMsg
        placeholderText: qsTr("Enter message")
        width: parent.width - 30
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.bottomMargin: 2
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 1
        focus: true
        wrapMode: TextArea.Wrap
        background: Rectangle {
            border.color: "#BDC3C7"
            border.width: 2
            color: "#ECF0F1"
        }
        onTextChanged: {
            listView.anchors.bottomMargin = height;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't have deleted your answer. It worked for me. The problem was my listview wasn't getting scrolled to bottom which made me think it didn't work. I fixed that. I still get the binding loop error though. @coyotte508

Comment: @coyotte508 maybe I can see your answer again to see the binding loop problem and accept it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    visible: true
    width : 500
    height: 300

    ListModel {
        id: contactModel
        ListElement {
            name: "Bill Smith"
            number: "555 3264"
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "John Brown"
            number: "555 8426"
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "Sam Wise"
            number: "555 0473"
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: contactDelegate
        Item {
            width: 180; height: 80
            Column {
                Text { text: '<b>Name:</b> ' + name }
                Text { text: '<b>Number:</b> ' + number }
            }
        }
    }


    ListView {
        id: listView
        anchors.top: parent.top;
        anchors.left: parent.left;
        anchors.right: parent.right;
        anchors.bottom: rectInput.top;

        model: contactModel
        delegate: contactDelegate
    }

    Rectangle{
        id: rectInput
        height: tMsg.height+4;
        color: "#BDC3C7"
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        width: parent.width

        TextArea{
            id: tMsg

            width: parent.width - 2
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.bottomMargin: 2
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.leftMargin: 1
            focus: true
            wrapMode: TextArea.Wrap
        }
    }
}
```

A sample qml file works fine. When in doubt, simplify, fix the problem and add back bit by bit.

In your code:

```
height: childrenRect.height + 6
```

<s>I don't see `childrenRect` defined anywhere. Maybe replacing it by `tMsg.height` and anchoring the list's bottom to the rectangle's top would work? It works in my sample file (I can't use your code word-for-word because it's not complete on its own).</s> Replacing `childrenRect` by `tMsg` removes the **binding loop** error for me.

By the way: I put the bottom of the list view to the rect's top, not to the text area's top which is inside the rect:

```
anchors.bottom: rectInput.top
```

An alternative would be to do in the list view:

```
anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
anchors.bottomMargin: tMsg.height
```

Apart from a warning at launch when the text view is not yet created, it works fine too.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply and the suggestion for best practises. I just want to confirm if the answer you posted works for you? Because I don't see a TextArea in the `rectInput` of your code which will actually be the one whose size gets changed. And the height of the listview needs to get changed according to it.

Comment: The `childrenRect` is a property of Item class. It even displays the height correctly when logged.

Comment: I tried your solution, unfortunately the listview won't reduce in height when the rows of textfield gets increased.

Comment: @AkashAggarwal edited again, with a possible answer to the binding loop problems. Deleted my old comments as well as not relevant to the final answer.

Comment: Thank you! The binding loop problem is now gone as well. It's strange for the `childrenRect` property to cause the error though.

Comment: Probably because changing the height of the item potentially changes its childrenRect as well, thus creating a loop if the height depends on it.

Comment: Height of textarea changes, height of childRect of rectInput changes which contains textarea, height of rectInput changes. I don't see a loop here. 
Also, If you'd like to update the answer with a better approach for anyone else reading this, setting `anchors.bottom: rectInput.top` for listview worked as well.